# Copy & Paste Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is my current script which works wonderfully. The range B5:J100 is currently being copied and pasted to the correct position in the sheet. However, the clearContent area must only start from B7:J100. How can I put that in the script?

Update: Can you show me where i have to write this new section? I am complete new to scripts and dont know how to do this.

```
 function copyPaste() {
   var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var srcsh=ss.getSheetByName('Yard');
   var dessh=ss.getSheetByName('History Yard');
   var srcrg=srcsh.getRange('B5:J100');
   var data=srcrg.getValues();
   var desrg=dessh.getRange(dessh.getLastRow() + 1,1,96,9);
   desrg.setValues(data);
  
srcrg.clearContent()
   }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The very easy (and static) way would be to apply `clearContent()` on `sercsh.getRange('B7:J100')` instead of `srcrg`.

If you want that to be (somewhat) dynamic, you could also use [Offset](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset,-numrows) on your `srcrg` variable (offset 2 rows, number of rows decreased with 2).

Comment: Hey Benibis, first of all thanks for the fast answer. For clarification: Im a complete newbie on scripts. So i dont know how to do this. I just want that the CopyPaste works on B5:J100 and the clearContent have to be on B7:j100. Is it possible that you can help me with this script and show me where i have to write this?

Comment: Hi Sebastian. In the last line of your script, simply make the replacement I suggested in the first paragraph of my answer, that should do the trick. So, simply replace `srcrg.clearContent()` with `srcsh.getRange('B7:J100').clearContent()`.